# GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation, windows

Tags: php, gd

i'm using php 8.1.4, laravel v9, xampp v3.3.0
in php.ini file i've changed ;extension=gd to extension=gd, but it still show the same error

Comment: Did you restart the webserver?

Comment: yes i've restarted xampp and use php artisan serve too

Comment: Is this the same php.ini file from `php --info` or `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Hi.
You do not precise the OS you're using Xampp. It will help people to help you !

Comment: Thanks everyone, i've reinstalled xampp with php 8.1.6 and it helped